# React Native: Is it possible to increase the touch area of a navigational swipe action?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, swipe, interactivepopgesture

I've been trying to find out if it is possible to increase the swipe left action(interactivePopGesture) to navigate to a previous screen in React Native.  I know that you can increase the touch area of buttons with hitSlop, but I wasn't sure if there was any way to increase the touch area for a swipe action to navigate to another scene.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a PR with this functionality was recently merged: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/commit/69397af74d3f36715b6e1a8fbc30a0bfd9c75778